# Select date and hour in query conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I am using PGADMIN 4 on postgres database. I would like to extract using the following query but adding hour as well. current date at 6am for example.

Thank you

```
SELECT object_key, audited_changes, created_at
FROM pg_audits
WHERE
source_action = 'funding' AND
created_at >= CURRENT_DATE -1 AND
created_at < CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY
created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write any number of hours in place of `N`

```
SELECT object_key, audited_changes, (created_at + INTERVAL 'N HOURS') as created_at 
FROM pg_audits
WHERE
source_action = 'funding' AND
created_at >= CURRENT_DATE -1 AND
created_at < CURRENT_DATE
ORDER BY
created_at DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much